# Figuring out which FCM tokens are expired from a firebase response with several registration ids

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase rest endpoint for push notifications lets you send a message to several people at once by passing the tokens through "registration_ids" array instead of "to". When the response comes back it looks like this:

```
{
   "multicast_id":000000000000000000,
   "success":1,
   "failure":4,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "error":"NotRegistered"
      },
      {
         "error":"NotRegistered"
      },
      {
         "error":"NotRegistered"
      },
      {
         "error":"NotRegistered"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:0000000000000000%a0a0a0aaa0a0a0aa"
      }
   ]
}
```

How are you supposed to correlate the NotRegistered errors to a particular token it was sent to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are in the same order as you specified them in the request. So only your last token was valid.

Comment: I didn't see that at all in the documentation but it seems to be correct. Thanks!